# Adding smooth fade/transition to jQuery hover function

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, background-image, fade

I've got a functional hover replace that inserts a background image on hover and removes it on mouseout.

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#l-1").hover(function() {
        $("#r-box").css("background","url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/up.png') no-repeat transparent");
            }, function() {
        $("#r-box").css("background","#3DA7BC");
    });
});
</script>
```

But I'm trying to get the transition to be smooth and graceful, not just in/out. I tried a variety of .animate functions to get it to work to no avail.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try out animating the opacity of the object in question using jQuery.

My algorithm goes something like this:

1) animate the opacity to some value which makes it more transparent

2) in the callback section, change the background image using `css({key:value})`

3) animate the opacity back to the original value

```
$('.your-base-object').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: '0.9'}, 300, function(){
            $(this).css({
                background: "url('path/to/your-image')"
            });
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: "1.0"
            }, 300);
        })
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: '0.9'}, 300, function(){
            $(this).css({
                background: "url('path/to/your-image')"
            });
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: "1.0"
            }, 300);
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely not be able to animate the background of an item like that.  From jQuery's animate page:

> All animated properties should be
>   animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties
>   that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery
>   functionality. (For example, width,
>   height, or left can be animated but
>   background-color cannot be.) Property
>   values are treated as a number of
>   pixels unless otherwise specified. The
>   units em and % can be specified where
>   applicable.

What I'd recommend doing is using some other way to display whatever's in the background image.  Perhaps put it in a hidden span tag and animate it by doing a fadeIn or a fadeOut.

Comment: It would not be hard to work around that with [cssHooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/), but what would you animate? There is no background image transparency in CSS; some browsers support it for simple background colors, but that won't help here.

Comment: One way I was thinking was to animate the div from the up state to the over state, but am at a loss at how to implement that transition.

Comment: Perhaps if you put together a jsfiddle with a bit more complete code of what you're trying to accomplish we might be able to provide a bit more insight / ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h4Tep/ It's not what the final page will look like, but gives you an idea of the setup I currently have... Thanks, Mark